# Google My Business API server to server without Workspace/G-Suite

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-places-api, google-my-business-api

i would like to achieve that the website of my PHP website can fetch business location data (name, address, contact, openings, ...) from the Google APIs, so that i do not have to insert the information twice.

I tried to create a service account and use it to authenticate against the My Business API. It did not work, as Google requires an OAuth2 token for this API.

How can i obtain a Oauth2 token using the service account without having a Google Workspace or G-Suite?

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually own or manage a location on Google Business Profile in order to be able to retrieve data for it. So for this you need a Google account.

An alternative for your usecase might be the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview). In order to use it, you need to create an API key via the Google Cloud console.

Comment: I own and manage a Google Business profile. I think i found the missing part now, i had to request the access to the Business API. In 2 weeks i should get the permission. At least i hope so.

Comment: If you mean you own only one single location, it's unlikely that your request will get approved.

Comment: No I own 3 locations atm..